# need finite xlim values in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

```
plot(mdhdi$Human.Development.Index..HDI.,mdhdi$SumOfMedals, xlab="HDI", ylab="Total Medals")
a = lm(mdhdi$SumOfMedals ~ mdhdi$Human.Development.Index..HDI.)
abline(a, col="red")
```

This code works well in script and gives me the plot with linear models.
However, when I'm trying to run exactly the same code in R markdown like below,

````
```{r}
plot(mdhdi$Human.Development.Index..HDI.,mdhdi$SumOfMedals, xlab="HDI", ylab="Total Medals")
a = lm(mdhdi$SumOfMedals ~ mdhdi$Human.Development.Index..HDI.)
abline(a, col="red")
```
````

It says, 'need finite xlim values'. I really don't understand why it gives me errors like that. Can anyone help me out, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is generated when you try and plot exclusively `NA` values:

```
> x=rep(NA,100)
> y=rnorm(100)
> plot(x,y)
#Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
```

This suggests maybe your dataset hasn't loaded properly earlier in your code. Alternatively try:

You can manually set the `xlim` values (the boundaries of the x axis) using the `xlim` argument.

Adding the argument `xlim = c(min(mdhdi$Human.Development.Index..HDI.), max(mdhdi$Human.Development.Index..HDI.)))` to your code may help. It won't actually change the axis, but will make explicit the x axis limits.

Comment: It may be because you haven't loaded your dataset in the markdown version. You normally get the error when you try and plot exclusively NA.